# Parsing of Noun Compounds

Tags: stanford-nlp

We have been using the corenlp package (june 2014 version; with default annotators) primarily for dependency parsing.

Recently, I have noticed a problem with the noun compound bracketing in cases like `"The Bank of England announced further interest rate increases today"` - the noun compound, `"interest rate increases"` is incorrectly bracketed (`interest` is parsed as modifying `increases` rather than `rate`).  This is also the case when you put this sentence in the online demo of the stanford parser, and with other similar sentences where a noun compound essentially modifies another noun.

One of my colleagues who does more parsing than I do says that this is likely due to the model having been trained on the unpatched version of the Penn Treebank.  And our own in-house parser which has been trained on the patched version does get (most of) these noun compounds correct.  I was wondering if there is an alternative pre-trained model for the Stanford corenlp parser which I am not aware of - and if there is, how we go about running the pipeline using this different model?